# React setselectedType does not immediately update the selectedType

Tags: javascript, react-redux, react-hooks, antd, ant-design-pro

I am setting the `selectedType` variable and opening ant design Modal containing ant design Form with initialValues filled with `selectedType`.

But the initialValues in the form are only working for the first time I click on Edit button and if I close the Modal and click on Edit button for a different selectedType the Modal shows the values of first time selected selectedType.

I have used `destroyOnClose={true}` for Modal to fetch the new value of `selectedType` but it doesn't solve the issue.

Here's my code:

```
import {
    Button, Form,
    Input,Table,
    Modal
} from "antd";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const ManageTypeScreen = () => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const productTypeList = useSelector(state => state.productTypeList);
        const [editForm] = Form.useForm();
        const [selectedType, setselectedType] = useState({});
        const [showEditModal, setshowEditModal] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
            getProductTypeList(dispatch);
    }, [])

const handleEditClose = () => {
            setshowEditModal(false);
        };

        const handleEditShow = (val) => {
            console.log(val);
            setselectedType(val);
            setshowEditModal(true);
        };

        const columns = [
            {
                title: 'Type Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                key: 'name'
            },
            {
                title: 'Short Cut',
                dataIndex: 'shortCut',
                key: 'shortCut'
            },
            {
                title: 'Edit',
                sortable: false,
                filterable: false,
                render: (text, pro) => (
                    <div>
                        <Button type="primary" size="sm block" onClick={() => handleEditShow(pro)}>
                            Edit
                        </Button>
                    </div>)
            },
        ];

        return (
      
                {selectedType !== undefined &&
                    
                    <Modal
                        title="Edit Type"
                        visible={showEditModal}
                        onCancel={handleEditClose}
                        destroyOnClose={true}
                        footer={null}
                        centered={true}
                    >
                        <Form
                            labelCol={{ span: 9 }}
                            wrapperCol={{ span: 12 }}
                            layout="horizontal"
                            form={editForm}
                            requiredMark={true}
                            initialValues={selectedType}
                            size="medium"
                        >

                            <Form.Item
                                label="Type Name:"
                                name="name"
                                rules={[
                                    { required: true, message: "Please input Name!" }
                                ]}>
                                <Input maxLength={32} />
                            </Form.Item>


                            <Form.Item
                                label="ShortCut"
                                name="shortCut"
                                rules={[
                                    {
                                        required: true,
                                        message: "Please input ShortCut!"
                                    }
                                ]}>
                                <Input maxLength={3} />
                            </Form.Item>
                            < Form.Item
                                wrapperCol={{
                                    span: 5,
                                    offset: 7
                                }}
                                style={{ marginTop: "35px" }}
                            >
                                <Button
                                    type="primary"
                                    htmlType="submit"
                                    size="large"
                                    loading={editLoading}
                                >
                                    Update Type
                         </Button>
                            </Form.Item>
                        </Form>
                    </Modal>
                }

               {
                    productTypeList !== undefined &&
                    <div style={{ marginLeft: "30px", marginRight: "30px" }}>
                        <Table
                            className="product-type-list-table"
                            columns={columns}
                            pagination={false}
                            dataSource={productTypeList}
                            rowKey={record => record.id}
                        />
                    </div>
                }
            </div >
        )
    }
```

Comment: What is the `pro` variable in the `render` function of the 3rd column?

Comment: @RonB. pro is the json object of row in the table.

Comment: e.g. {name:"abc", shortCut:"ABC"}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the solution, but I'd suggest not messing up the rendering of the modal with both conditional rendering and a `visible` prop, it makes it hard to track.

Try something like

```
visible={selectedType !== undefined && showEditModal}
```

Or better yet, just get rid of the `showEditModal` variable since you're always changing it in accord with `selectedType`.

I think you can do it by changing you close function to

```
const handleEditClose = () => {
            setshowEditModal(null);
        };
```

Set the initial value of `selectedType` to `null`

and your modal's props to

```
 <Modal
                        title="Edit Type"
                        visible={!!selectedType}
```

(Though it might give you an error because it might try to render the modal when `selectedType` is null, then just switch back to conditional rendering and set the `visible` prop to be always `true`)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ron. I really appreciate it. I have solved this issue by assigning initialvalue at the Form.Item level and doing preserve={false}.

Comment: e.g.     <Form.Item
                                label="Product Type Name:"
                                name="name"
                                initialValue={selectedType.name}
                                preserve={false}
                                rules={[
                                    { required: true, message: "Please input Name!" }
                                ]}>
                                <Input maxLength={32} />
                            </Form.Item>

Answer (score 0):

```
import {
    Button, Form,
    Input,Table,
    Modal
} from "antd";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const ManageTypeScreen = () => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const productTypeList = useSelector(state => state.productTypeList);
        const [editForm] = Form.useForm();
        const [selectedType, setselectedType] = useState({});
        const [showEditModal, setshowEditModal] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
            getProductTypeList(dispatch);
    }, [])

const handleEditClose = () => {
            setshowEditModal(false);
        };

        const handleEditShow = (val) => {
            console.log(val);
            setselectedType(val);
            setshowEditModal(true);
        };

        const columns = [
            {
                title: 'Type Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                key: 'name'
            },
            {
                title: 'Short Cut',
                dataIndex: 'shortCut',
                key: 'shortCut'
            },
            {
                title: 'Edit',
                sortable: false,
                filterable: false,
                render: (text, pro) => (
                    <div>
                        <Button type="primary" size="sm block" onClick={() => handleEditShow(pro)}>
                            Edit
                        </Button>
                    </div>)
            },
        ];

        return (
      
                {selectedType !== undefined &&
                    
                    <Modal
                        title="Edit Type"
                        visible={showEditModal}
                        onCancel={handleEditClose}
                        destroyOnClose={true}
                        footer={null}
                        centered={true}
                    >
                        <Form
                            labelCol={{ span: 9 }}
                            wrapperCol={{ span: 12 }}
                            layout="horizontal"
                            form={editForm}
                            requiredMark={true}
                            size="medium"
                        >

                            <Form.Item
                                label="Type Name:"
                                name="name"
                                initialValue={selectedType.name}
                                preserve={false}
                                rules={[
                                    { required: true, message: "Please input Name!" }
                                ]}>
                                <Input maxLength={32} />
                            </Form.Item>


                            <Form.Item
                                label="ShortCut"
                                name="shortCut"
                                initialValue={selectedType.shortCut}
                                preserve={false}
                                rules={[
                                    {
                                        required: true,
                                        message: "Please input ShortCut!"
                                    }
                                ]}>
                                <Input maxLength={3} />
                            </Form.Item>
                            < Form.Item
                                wrapperCol={{
                                    span: 5,
                                    offset: 7
                                }}
                                style={{ marginTop: "35px" }}
                            >
                                <Button
                                    type="primary"
                                    htmlType="submit"
                                    size="large"
                                    loading={editLoading}
                                >
                                    Update Type
                         </Button>
                            </Form.Item>
                        </Form>
                    </Modal>
                }

               {
                    productTypeList !== undefined &&
                    <div style={{ marginLeft: "30px", marginRight: "30px" }}>
                        <Table
                            className="product-type-list-table"
                            columns={columns}
                            pagination={false}
                            dataSource={productTypeList}
                            rowKey={record => record.id}
                        />
                    </div>
                }
            </div >
        )
    }
```